# How to change the character used for single-quotes in python code blocks of an R Markdown document?

Tags: python, r, r-markdown

Single-quotes in `python` code blocks of an `R Markdown` document look bad when rendered in `PDF` format. For example:

[image]

The single quotes are curled as if they are the ending quote. Is there a way to get straight single-quotes? Or is this the only single-quote character available in the default font?

One possibility is to replace them with double-quotes in the `python` code but I shouldn't have to alter working code.

Incidentally, for `R` code blocks the single-quotes are replaced with double-quotes in the `PDF` rendering. For example, the code `os <- import('os')` is rendered as:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature?

**Edit**. Here is an RME as requested in the comments, a sample `R Markdown` document:

````
---
title: "single-quotes"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
py_config()
```

Example `python` code block:

```{python}
d = dict()
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 0
d['a'] + d['b']
```

`R` code converts single-quote to double-quote:

```{r r-code}
os <- import('os')
os$getcwd()
```
````

**Update**. I noticed that when I run the sample `R Markdown` on my local machine, none of the above issues are present. However, when I run it on my rserver in the cloud I am getting the two issues above.

I guess the obvious place to look next is at the `R` and package versions, but maybe someone already knows what is going on?

Comment: Can you provide a sample Markdown document that can be used for testing? That will make it much easier to help you and test possible solutions

Comment: @MrFlick Done, and note the update too.